# On $L^* - \{\epsilon\} = L^+$

Tags: automata, equality

> $\Sigma^* - \{\epsilon\} = \Sigma^+$
>
> $L^* - \{\epsilon\} = L^+$
>
> Which of the above is always true?

I was following a discussion on a site and I came across this question. Some fellow scholars claimed that the second statement is not always true. 
The answer they provided is this:

> $S_1$: $Σ^* – \{ϵ\} = Σ^+$: TRUE  // Always true, definition of $Σ^+$
>
> $S_2$: $L^* – \{ϵ\} = L^+$: FALSE // May or may not be true
>
> False when $ϵ$ belongs to $L$, then $L^+$ and $L^*$ will both contain $ϵ$.
>
> PS: In $S_2$, it depends purely on the given language.

But I have this doubt:

How can $L^+$ contain $ϵ$? we obtain $L^+$ by deleting $ϵ$ from $L^*$, and in $L^*$ of the language where $L=\{ϵ\}$, $L^*$ will only contain $ϵ$, so if we remove $ϵ$ from it, then the language should become $\emptyset$, which is nothing but $L^+$ here. So shouldn't the second statement also be true?

Say $L^+  = \{ϵ,ϵϵ,ϵϵϵ,\dots\}$.

Now an important point. Note that we say **Set of all strings**, now in set theory duplicates are not allowed, moreover $ϵ= ϵϵ =ϵϵϵ =\dots$. They are all just the same. So $L^∗$ should be only $\{ϵ\}$, rather than $\{ϵ,ϵ,ϵϵ,ϵϵϵ,\dots\}$, right?

Comment: Usual definition is $L^+ = L \cdot L^*$.

Comment: see my doubt above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got the definition of $L^+$ wrong. It is *not* $L^* \setminus \{\epsilon\}$. Rather, it is
$$
L^+ = \bigcup_{n=1}^* L^n.
$$
You can check that $\epsilon \in L^+$ iff $\epsilon \in L$. Therefore:

- If $\epsilon \notin L$ then $L^+ = L^*\setminus\{\epsilon\}$.
- If $\epsilon \in L$ then $L^+ = L^*$.

Comment: Thank u sir... :)